# Oracle SQL query to pivot like excel

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like pivot using sql query below would be my data format:

| Date | Sales | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07-May | Coffee | 20 |
| 07-May | Tea | 50 |
| 07-May | Chia | 30 |
| 14-May | Tea | 40 |
| 14-May | Coffee | 60 |

I would like my data to be output using oracle sql query to be in the below format:

| Sale | 07-May | 14-May |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Coffee | 20 | 60 |
| Chia |  | 30 |
| Tea | 50 | 40 |

Could you please assist over here?

Comment: if you have 11g, `pivot` is the thing to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730111/pivoting-rows-into-columns-dynamically-in-oracle https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html  https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot  Also related to using pivot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103060/oracle-pivot-query-gives-columns-with-quotes-around-the-column-names-what

Comment: If you don't have 11g, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245367/how-to-pivot-a-table-in-oracle-plsql  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537526/oracle-sql-pivot-table-rows-to-column-and-use-sub-query-in-pivot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use pivot like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT Date,Sales,Count
  FROM your_table
)
PIVOT
(
  sum(Count)
  FOR Date IN ('07-May', '14-May')
) ;
```

Comment: I would like to pass the date range rather than mentioning individual dates as that would ensure that i am not missing any date.